# Merging two identical two identical tibbles in R to collapse their missing values

Tags: r, join, merge, missing-data

I am working with R.

I have two tibbles (data frames) that look like this...

tibble1:

```
ID   value1   value2   value3   value4

A      0.1      0.2      0.7      0.5
B      NA        NA       NA       NA
C      0.2      0.7      0.5      0.3
D      NA        NA       NA       NA
E      0.3      0.4      0.6      0.8
D      NA        NA       NA       NA
F      NA        NA       NA       NA
```

tibble 2

```
ID   value1   value2   value3   value4

A      NA       NA       NA       NA
B      0.3      0.04     0.8     0.05
C      NA       NA       NA       NA
D      0.37     0.62     0.63    0.64
E      NA       NA       NA       NA
D      NA       NA       NA       NA
F      0.4      0.5      0.6      0.07
```

I have tried to merge them or left join them and the problem that I have is that I get a result in which i get value1x, value2x, value 3x, value 4x, value1y, value2y, value3y,value4y

So, I need to colapse them because they compliment each other. They need to look like this...

tibble1&tibble2

```
ID   value1   value2   value3   value4

A      0.1      0.2      0.7      0.5
B      0.3      0.04     0.8     0.05
C      0.2      0.7      0.5      0.3
D      0.37     0.62     0.63    0.64
E      0.3      0.4      0.6      0.8
D      NA       NA       NA       NA
F      0.4      0.5      0.6      0.07
```

Thanks!

Comment: "two identical two identical" - typo or joke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can use `coalesce` - works on data frames or tibbles as well as vectors.

```
library(dplyr)
coalesce(tbl1, tbl2)
# # A tibble: 7 x 5
#   ID    value1 value2 value3 value4
#   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A       0.1    0.2    0.7    0.5 
# 2 B       0.3    0.04   0.8    0.05
# 3 C       0.2    0.7    0.5    0.3 
# 4 D       0.37   0.62   0.63   0.64
# 5 E       0.3    0.4    0.6    0.8 
# 6 D      NA     NA     NA     NA   
# 7 F       0.4    0.5    0.6    0.07
```

Comment: Ah. I was sure there was a tidyverse function that did this, but couldn't remember the name and figured it would be quicker to write a quick loop in base R. This should be the accepted answer, and gets my UV, but I'll leave my answer up as a base R solution.

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop could achieve this:

```r
for(i in seq_along(tbl1)) {
  tbl1[[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(tbl1[[i]]), tbl2[[i]], tbl1[[i]])
}
```

Leaving

```
tbl1
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>      ID value1 value2 value3 value4
#>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1   0.1    0.2    0.7    0.5 
#> 2     2   0.3    0.04   0.8    0.05
#> 3     3   0.2    0.7    0.5    0.3 
#> 4     4   0.37   0.62   0.63   0.64
#> 5     5   0.3    0.4    0.6    0.8 
#> 6     4  NA     NA     NA     NA   
#> 7     6   0.4    0.5    0.6    0.07
```

---

**Data**

```r
tbl1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L), 
.Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), value1 = c(0.1, 
NA, 0.2, NA, 0.3, NA, NA), value2 = c(0.2, NA, 0.7, NA, 0.4, 
NA, NA), value3 = c(0.7, NA, 0.5, NA, 0.6, NA, NA), value4 = c(0.5, 
NA, 0.3, NA, 0.8, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

tbl2 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L), 
.Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), value1 = c(NA, 0.3, 
NA, 0.37, NA, NA, 0.4), value2 = c(NA, 0.04, NA, 0.62, NA, NA, 
0.5), value3 = c(NA, 0.8, NA, 0.63, NA, NA, 0.6), value4 = c(NA, 
0.05, NA, 0.64, NA, NA, 0.07)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fcoalesce`

```
library(data.table)
data.frame(Map(fcoalesce, tbl1, tbl2))
#  ID value1 value2 value3 value4
#1  A   0.10   0.20   0.70   0.50
#2  B   0.30   0.04   0.80   0.05
#3  C   0.20   0.70   0.50   0.30
#4  D   0.37   0.62   0.63   0.64
#5  E   0.30   0.40   0.60   0.80
#6  D     NA     NA     NA     NA
#7  F   0.40   0.50   0.60   0.07
```